# Google Chrome, WebWorks, HTML5Database, transaction() and alert - transaction callback not called

Tags: google-chrome, blackberry-webworks, ripple

We've run into a strange situation. We're calling a `database.transaction(txCallback, txError, txSuccess)`, 
and if we follow the transaction call with an `alert()` call, the `txSuccess` function is called without the 
`txCallback` function ever being called.

Is this a known error, or documented behaviour with a reasonable explanation?

It seems only to occur in the Ripple Emulator and in Google Chrome (which Ripple is based on). It **does not** occur in Safari, where it operates as expected, whether using `alert` or `console.log`.

This HTML demonstrates the situation well:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function dbalert() {
  var db = window.openDatabase("test","1.0","test",1024*1024);
  console.log("Next line should read: In transaction callback");
  window.transactionCalled = false;
  db.transaction(
    function (tx) {
        console.log("In transaction callback");
        window.transactionCalled = true;
    },
    function (tx, err) {
        console.error("ERROR");
        console.log(err);
    },
    function () {
        if (window.transactionCalled) {
            console.log("Success callback: everything worked!");
        } else {
            console.error("Success callback: BUT TRANSACTION WAS NEVER CALLED");
        }
    }
  );
  /*****
   * Change to FALSE to get this working.
   *****/
  if (true) {
    alert("Ok, let's see what happened");
  } else {
    console.log("Ok, let's see what happened");
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="dbalert();">
<div id="out">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Appears this http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=60501 provides some discussion of what is considered a Chromium bug. The offending call is `alert` which suspends all `ActiveDOMObjects`, and the transaction callback is never requeued. The problem seems to have existed since at least 2010...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the bug is a timing issue.

Database transactions are asyncronous, while alert statements are synchronous (block the UI) so the transaction call is not guaranteed to have finished when the alert statement is executed:

> > if we follow the transaction call with an alert() call

Suggest removing alert() statements completely.